# How to generate keypair completely offline?

Tags: address, private-key

Is it possible to generate address and private key pair completely offline, using only dice / other random number generators, calculators, paper and pen? If yes, whats the procedure and formulas used?

Comment: Is there a reason for asking this question?

Comment: Just to be extra careful.. may be its more of a trouble than what its worth. I will choose an offline desktop. :)

Comment: Like this one? http://www.furniturebydovetail.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/desk-organizing.jpg

Comment: No, that's just a desk.. :)

Comment: Actually, that's a wise question to ask, even offline hardwares may have a pre-defined pattern for generating random numbers. So no complete privacy is guaranteed by using hardware systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create such keypairs offline, but the calculations are long and complex. You would need to find out how to:

1) Create a secp256k1 public key from a private key

2) Perform SHA-256 hashing

3) Perform RIPEMD-160 hashing

4) Be able to convert the final value into Base 58

Generally, the calculations would be very tedious; this is what we have computers for.

Comment: Yeah, no one should be doing this by hand...

Comment: Also, if you made any mistakes, you'd be sending your coins into the void.

Answer (score 3):

A good article on keypair generation
http://www.swansontec.com/bitcoin-dice.html

Essentially, you can generate your private key using dice, and use a computer to derive an address from that private key.

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions to create a Bitcoin address and associated key-pair completely offline. It is straight from the Bitcoin Wiki.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_secure_offline_savings_wallet

Answer (score 0):

This working computer example complements @ThePiachu.

Let's assume your random number generator mechanism generated this very low entropy 256-bit number in hexadecimal format that will become the private key:

0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff

**1. Associated compressed Bitcoin WIF-encoded private key:**

% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | sed 's/$/01/' | bx base58check-encode -v 128

**`KwDiDMtpksBAcfyHsVS5XzmirtyjKWSeaeM9U1QppugixMUeKMqp`**

**2. Associated compressed Bitcoin public address:**

% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public | bx ec-to-address -v 0

**`1PbStXjfDNBU6FZA2iSeisVWwCFN9GK1eQ`**